# How do I change the colours in SharpDevelop to a dark theme?

Tags: themes, sharpdevelop

I love the textmate themes, specifically I like 'Twilight' but Im happy with any dark textmate like theme's to use with SharpDevelop.

The posts I've found online so far have all had broken links to the source/code.

Answer (score 3):

There are no themes for SharpDevelop, but you can use Tools > Options > Text Editor > Highlighting to change the colors of the text editor.

Comment: Now you should change the sentence to "there was no themes" :) http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/christophwille/archive/2012/08/13/import-and-export-of-highlighting-settings.aspx

Comment: There are really no themes in term of docks and toolbars around the source-code window. So, even if you change code highlighting colors to a dark theme, the rest of the SharpDevelop will remain bright-white, torturing your eyes with insane contrast.
Compare: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HLt6A.jpg
With: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/photos/christophwille/images/43107/640x454.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you use SharpDevelop 5, you can use my custom theme (tailored mainly for c#).
Add the following content within the *properties* tag in *%APPDATA%\ICSharpCode\SharpDevelop5\SharpDevelopProperties.xml*

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/711ae44acb9a570690dd

Answer (score 3):

In Tools -> Text Editor -> Highlighting there is an option "Import highlighting colors" and supports both vss ans sd settings. 
My favorite setting is Son of Obsidian, here is the link:
https://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian
Or google for the theme you like and import it :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this :)